# CSS simple lines don't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap CDN. From the 3 rules, the last 2 ones don't work. Neither the image is resized nor the heading change its font color.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Custom styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./stylesheets/portada.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="section1">
            <h2 class="text-center">Heading</h2>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/8.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.section1 {                        // Working
background-color: #363b48;
color: blue;
height: 100px;
}

.section1 .text-center{             // Not working
    color: #985475;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}

.section1 img{                      //Not working
    width:20px;
}
```

Comment: These are working fine over a jsfiddle I created. I think the problem is that other styles are overriding the ones you're trying to do.

Comment: I removed both the bootstrap css and script line and jquery script and it still doesn't work :\

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPbZmQ


Try this link, hope it will help;)

Comment: I swear to God I'm copying the same code and adding a link for the CSS and it doesn't work, neither in chrome nor mozilla

Comment: Seems to work fine indeed. The problem is probably somewhere else in your custom `portada.css`. Try inspecting the elements in question to find out where their styling is coming from.

Comment: portada.css consists in those 3 lines, there are no more so far.... if I remove the bootstrap lines, it doesn't work. @ImAtWar code works in that site, but not in the browser

Comment: Do you save the files on your pc? Could be local use does have some problems with fetching stylesheets from the web.

Comment: Do you mean bootstrap? I'm using the links, just as shown, the CDN. Regarding the rest of the files, I do have them stored locally in my Desktop

Comment: You could also check if your browser, can or cannot fetch the urls, Do so using Chrome.. press Right mouse button, click inspect element. check this url for screenshot which error you should check,.


http://oi59.tinypic.com/2h84c48.jpg

Comment: When I do so, I cannot find anything similar to your screenshot :\

Comment: http://oi60.tinypic.com/1yuatj.jpg, truth be told, your problem seems to be lost on me.. however you can check if your browser cant view some resources.. Try checking google's web developer tools if you still cant make sense of it.. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Let me know if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Try `.section1 > .text-center{` and `.section1 > img{`

Comment: It actually works on your jsfiddle link look [see](https://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/undmcszz/9/)

Comment: Then how is it possible that the code works in jsfiddle or codepen but not in the browser, neither chrome nor mozilla? I'm just creating a html file and open it with the browser, I haven't set up any server.

Comment: _"how is it possible that the code works in jsfiddle or codepen but not in the browser"_ — because you are opening your `.html` file _locally_ with the `file://` protocol which, as @ImAtWar mentions in a previous comment, has problems fetching remote stylesheets.  If you put your exact same html and css files on a server they should work. Or run a webserver on your own machine and get `http://localhost/path/to/your.html`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, although what you have should work also

```
.section1 h2{           
color: #985475;
margin-top: 20px;
background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed 2 issues in your code.

- First the **CDN should not be loaded over http**, but https. For
  cross domain issues when loading it it's better to use just the **//**
  without the http or https. That way it will load without giving crossdomain issues.

For instance: `<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

- Second is that you are using **comments** which should be /* */
  instead of // single slashes because they are on the same line with
  some CSS code.

Look after fixing these how it looks:

```
.section1 {                        /* Working*/
background-color: #363b48;
color: blue;
height: 100px;
}

.section1 .text-center{             /* Working*/
    color: #985475;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}

.section1 img{                      /* Working*/
    width:20px;
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/undmcszz/9/

Comment: Nope. The thing is, when I'm using jsfiddle or codepen, it perfectly works: the lines are really simple and in fact I've continued developing my web. Yet, it doesn't work on my browser, should I have anything special installed?

Comment: Not at all, only if I remove http. Instead I changed it and used https but nothing working anyway. By the way, i added the CSS comments while writing the post, I don't have them in the CSS code, sorry for the mistake while adding them for the post.

Comment: not https but // only. I posted an example there. It's ok no worries for the comments.

Comment: yes, I mean if I use just "//maxcdn. ...." I got an error because it doesn't load the files. file://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure, but I would bet the problem lies in portada.css as it is (presumably) available on your local env, but not on the online code editors.

Css rules have weight depending on specificity. Even when you supply new rules on top of older ones, the weightiest rule will be applied. See this site to help calculate specificity: http://specificity.keegan.st/

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should has the next code at the first lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```