# CSS not working locally in my computer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to develop a website and recently I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722941/css-simple-lines-dont-work) a question because some custom simple lines in CSS weren't working. I discovered that using development sites such as jsfiddle or codepen, the code works but I can't still get it working in my computer.

Do I need to install do something or install something? I thought it could be an issue of not using a web server, but I've just installed XAMPP and nothing...

In the end, I'm using XAMPP, with proper path xampp_path/etsit/index.html --> localhost/etsit/index.html. This doesn't work, there's no error in the cosole. When I just click in index.html to open it with the browser, it doesn't work either.

For bootstrap, I just add these links to the body (JUST FOR YOU TO KNOW I HAVEN'T DOWNLOADED BOOTSTRAP BUT I'M USING CDN):

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

Sample in [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPbZmQ) and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/undmcszz/9/) that work.

The original (it's the same code) you can find it in these other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722941/css-simple-lines-dont-work) I made.

**UPDATE 2**
Please, read the post entirely before editing my question and marking it as duplicate, not noticing that same question is mine and has been referenced twice in the post....

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ? If yes, adjust proxy settings

Comment: Look in the browsers error console

Comment: I have no proxy. Eve not using the server, if I just click on the html linked to my custom css, it doesn't work on the browser, whose console by the way shows no error

Comment: This is missing a lot of information required to determine the answer to your question. Is it a static website or is it running on a server? If it is the latter, are you running a server? You mentioned you installed XAMPP - are you running it properly and pointing it to the directory where your website is located? Are you getting any errors in your browser console? Which CSS lines are not working - yours or Bootstrap's?

Comment: I've just updated the post: no error, yes properly running (otherwise I would see an error and not the page), my CSS lines don't work

Comment: Where's the code that shows how your CSS is loaded? The only CSS I see above is a CDN link to Bootstrap's CSS.

Comment: Would you please supply as with a demo site ?
It can be a bad reference to a directory or something like that.

Comment: Okay, so you're not getting errors and your server is running properly. Where is your link to your CSS? The code supplied in your question does not specify anything other than Bootstrap CSS, jQuery, and Bootstrap JS. You'll need a link to your own CSS in order for it to be applied to your pages.

Comment: Those lines are just to show you how I'm linking bootstrap files, my files are properly linked too if you take a look at the other post, see my update

Comment: If you put the CSS from portada.css in the HTML file itself instead of linking to it, does it work?

Comment: When you load your page, open your dev tools in your browser and look at the network tab. Do you see your CSS file loading?

Comment: Hi @Fernando, Can you try to access by browser to some of the resources that you're trying to import in your HTML? like https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css
If you can, you could download those files and use they localy. If you can't, that's because you have some firewall or proxy denying that protocol.

Comment: @j08691 if I use style tag rather than style one, it works!!! how is this possible?

Comment: @AlbertFM yes, I can see them.

Comment: @Tim McClure I can't :\

Comment: What browser are you using? Could you try a different one and see if that works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS simple lines don't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722941/css-simple-lines-dont-work)

Comment: @Stephen P those lines are mine and are referenced on my post twice

Comment: @Fernando - I know it's yours, you've asked the same question twice, just in slightly different ways. My vote to close stands.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answers in the comments section, it seems as though you are not loading your CSS file. You've stated that you do indeed have a link to it in your in your code. So either a) that link is now gone (in which case you would not see it at all in your dev tools' network tab); or b) the link is incorrect (in which case you would be getting something like a 404 error in your network tab). Make sure the path to your CSS file is indeed correct and that it exists at the location that you are defining.

Comment: yeah, i've checked that, it's in the same folder, I'm using '<link rel="stylesheet" href="./portada.css">'

Comment: Regarding the dev tools, i've never worked with that and not even when I add the style inline I'm able to find it, speaking frankly

Comment: First - which browser are you using? Second - try removing the '.' or './'

Comment: With inline style tag I see the properties are added. I'm using chrome, but it doesn't work in mozilla firefox either. If I switch between '.' ,  './' and  '/' I get different results

Comment: Can you clarify what those different results are? Does one of those actually work? 

In Chrome, right click on the page and select Inspect Element in the context menu that appears. In the panel that opens, click on the network tab. Reload your page at this point. You should see files that your page loads begin to populate that panel. Look for your CSS file in that panel.

Comment: ok, it see the file is loaded. The difference is "/portada.css" is wrong, you can't use it. "portada.css" and "./portada.css" do the same, but it's not what it should be

Comment: ... I'm confused. So the file is loading successfully with one of those links?

Comment: it's strange, now it's worked but after I changed a line in the css. It's as though it has to make an effort to load the file haha