# Why is my CSS not being applied? It worked on codeine but not VSCode

Tags: html, css

So I'm new to programming and I've been learning on my own through the Odin Project.  The first project I've been working on is a recreation of the Google search site. I've got some of the basic HTML layout but my CSS is not being applied, I originally started this project on codepin and everything worked. When I switched to vscode... nothing. Here's what I have so far for HTML and CSS.

```css
.flex-container {
   height: 100vh;
   border: 3px solid blue;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center; /* x-axis */ 
   align-items: center; /* y-axis */
   }
 
 .flex-item {
   font-size: 90px;
   font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;

#G {
   color: #4885ed;
 }
 #o {
   color: #db3236;
 }
 
 #o1 {
   color: #f4c20d;
 }
 
 #g {
   color: #4885ed;
 }
 
 #l {
   color: #3cba54;
 }
 
 #e {
   color: #db3236;
 }
 
 .foot {
   background-color: #A5A6A1;
   height: 2em;
   
 }
 
 .ad {
   color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google</title>
    <style>     
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Noto+Sans+JP&display=swap');
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class ='flex-container'>
      <!-- Try using 'span' instead of a div for 'Google'.-->
      <div class='flex-item'>
        <span id='G'>G</span>
        <span id='o'>o</span>
        <span id='o1'>o</span>
        <span id='g'>g</span>
        <span id='l'>l</span>
        <span id='e'>e</span>
      </div>
      <input type="Search">
    </div>
    <footer class='foot'>
      <span id='ad'>Advertising</span>
      <span>Business</span>
      <span>How search works</span>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my first post so hopefully its a good question.  Any and all help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Given that you started on Code pen, you likely forgot to link your css file to your html file. To do that take a look at the link tag https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Comment: What do you mean by "...nothing"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS not working locally in my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851686/css-not-working-locally-in-my-computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to link your css file to your html file. Add a link tag at the end of the head tag, in case you have the html and css files in the same directory and your css file's name is `styles`, you can do like this:

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

The reason it works on Codepen is because they do the linking work for you, so the html, js and css file are automatically connected to each other

Comment: Thank you!  Its working now. still learning lol

Answer (score 0):

Looking at CSS code it seems like it is in different file. So in this case you have to link CSS to HTML file you can do this by using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourfilepath">` inside head tag.

Answer (score 0):

-- You have to call the css file that you made with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="the file of the css">
```